# How to correctly add google-services.json to Xamarin forms android?

Tags: firebase, xamarin, xamarin.forms, google-cloud-firestore, xamarin.android

I'm new to Xamarin Forms. I have created an account at Firebase Firestore and downloaded the google-services.json file and added it to the Android project.

I installed Xamarin.Firebase.Common + Xamarin.Firebase.Firestore + Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging + Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement.

When I add 'GoogleServicesJson' under Build Action, that app crashes at startup (break down mode) (without reaching any Firestore code).
When I remove the Build Action to None the app works (without the Firestore services).

I didn't write my Firestore code because the app crashes before reaching any of it.

I checked the package name again and found no errors.

What did I do wrong?

Edit with more info:

Error:

> Java.Lang.NoDefFounderError: 'Failed resolution of :Lcom/google/android/datatrsnport/runtime/dagger/internal/Factory';

Versions:

- Minimum Android version: 5.0 Target Android version: 1 (API 30 -R)
- Xamarin.Essentials: 1.7.0
- Xamarin.Firebase.Common 120.0.0
- Xamarin.Firebase.Firestore 123.0.2
- Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging 122.0.0
- Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement 117.6.0.1

JSON file:

```
{
  "project_info": {
    "project_number": "434321905143",
    "project_id": "jeelbook-cbcdc",
    "storage_bucket": "jeelbook-cbcdc.appspot.com"
  },
  "client": [
    {
      "client_info": {
        "mobilesdk_app_id": "1:434321905143:android:594a575ad8bdcc1512682a",
        "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "com.attendance.jeelbookgit"
        }
      },
      "oauth_client": [
        {
          "client_id": "434321905143-1bp9fspsluume0mq736t3rcpo6nmt85p.apps.googleusercontent.com",
          "client_type": 3
        }
      ],
      "api_key": [
        {
          "current_key": "AIzaSyAzpEmGhiw11wijToKfk5N8UVYujG2y-B0"
        }
      ],
      "services": {
        "appinvite_service": {
          "other_platform_oauth_client": [
            {
              "client_id": "434321905143-1bp9fspsluume0mq736t3rcpo6nmt85p.apps.googleusercontent.com",
              "client_type": 3
            },
            {
              "client_id": "434321905143-a4rhej5qj29rad4qct44gta9ioa3m7eb.apps.googleusercontent.com",
              "client_type": 2,
              "ios_info": {
                "bundle_id": "com.companyname.jeelBookGit"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "configuration_version": "1"
}
```

[image]

Comment: 1. Any info from Output? 2. Which link are you following? 3. What is your Android Target framework? 4. Could you post a screenshot of your json file's properties?

Comment: thanks for your comment. 1) regarding output, as I wrote it's just (Break down mode - unhandled exception - with nothing to tell). I tried to set breakPoint on MainActivity but it crashes before. 2) I used: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EkrONAJrpzs&list=PLehqRG9c-ovaFilQkVvblioONDbnn3VU9&index=12 + https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/push/migration/xamarin-android
3) versions: Minimum Android version: 5.0 Target Android version: 1 (API 30 -R) Xaramin.Essentials: 1.7.0   Xaramin.Firebase.Common 120.0.0  
4) will upload a screenshot.  thanks

Comment: solved!
Installing the Xamarin.Google.Dagger package solved this problem for me.

Comment: It's **Xamarin** - not "Xaramin" ....